# running playframework under cygwin

Tags: playframework

any one tried running playframework under cygwin environment? i get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\installedSoft\play-2.0.1/framework/sbt/sbt.boot.properties
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:859)
    at java.net.URI.resolve(URI.java:1043)
    at xsbt.boot.Configuration$.resolve$1(Configuration.scala:50)
    at xsbt.boot.Configuration$$anonfun$1.apply(Configuration.scala:56)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$21.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at xsbt.boot.Configuration$.configurationFromFile(Configuration.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Configuration$.find(Configuration.scala:25)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:14)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:25)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:15)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
```

Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\installedSoft\play-2.0.1/framework/sbt/sbt.boot.properties
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3002)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3039)
        at java.net.URI.(URI.java:595)
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:857)
        ... 10 more
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\installedSoft\play-2.0.1/framework/sbt/sbt.boot.properties

Answer (score 3):

I have tried with Play 1.2.4, and it worked as long as instead of e.g. "play run" I used "play.bat run".

However, when stopping the app, the java process would sometimes keep on running and holding the 9000 port, making it impossible to start the app again until you don't kill it manually from task manager.

This would not be an issue if instead of **play.bat run** I used **play.bat start** then to tail logs **play.bat out** and to stop the app: **play.bat stop**.